# Can't store data in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

customers_form.html

```
      <form>
        <fieldset class='text-center'>
          <legend>Create your Account</legend>
            <div>
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token%}
                    {% include 'registration/form-template.html' %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div align="center" >
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="submit"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <a href="forgot_password.html">Forgot password?</a>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

form-template.html

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-som-offset-2 col-som-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label >{{ field.label_tag }}{{ field }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'registration'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='registration'),
    url(r'^customer/add/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='customer-add'),

]
```

proj/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import urls
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('registration.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))

]
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import customers
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views import View
from .forms import UserForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'registration/home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return customers.objects.all()


class UserFormView(View):
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'registration/customers_form.html'

    # display blank form
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    # process form data
    def post(self,request):
       form = self.form_class(request.POST)

       if form.is_valid():
           user = form.save(commit=False)

           username = form.cleaned_data['username']
           password = form.cleaned_data['password']
           user.set_password(password)
           user.save()

           # return username if credentials are correct
           user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

           if user is not None:

                if user.is_active:
                   login(request, user)
                   return redirect('registration:index')
       return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

when i clicked on signup button then it redirects back to the signup form and does not show any error. Everything is working but not stored data in the User model of django.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
         ]
```

I want to register the users in django's User model, but i can't.

Comment: Please provide your form and models. Also, try to explain the purpose of this page in english. No one wants to interpret what you want to do through code because it might be wrong and is painful to interpret.

Comment: I want to register the users, using django's 'django.contrib.auth.urls'. but when i clicked on the submit button, then nothing happen and it again redirects to the signup page..

Answer (score 1):

Your form tag has no action...

`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

The `action` attribute tells the form where to post to. That should be the URL of where your POST data goes. Also it doesn't look like you have any inputs...

Comment: in registering the users what could be in action attribute??

Comment: I believe for you that would be `customer/add`.

Comment: it does not work... Any other solution?? #JakeDenison

Comment: Double check that you have the URL right. Check out this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/). I guarantee you that this is the issue.